# What was that feature request web app SO used before meta came along?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange-history

I remember when SO first started up, there was an outside website they used for tracking/voting on feature requests.  Anyone remember what that was?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

UserVoice: [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20090219112537/http://stackoverflow.uservoice.com:80/)

Comment: And very nasty it was,

Comment: Nasty?  A friend was asking for a tool for such things, and I thought of that... is it not a good one?

Comment: I'm amazed it still resolves to a valid site.

Comment: @Telos: for a small project with a small number of users and feature requests, it would probably work... Then again, so would almost anything. The problem SO had was a large number of users, a huge number of feature requests, bug reports, and commentary on both. UV didn't allow formatting or attachments - so right away, it sucked for bug reports or features that would benefit from some sort of screenshot or mock-up drawing. Linking was incredibly flaky - forget linking to individual comments, even linking to top-level posts was prone to breakage... try loading almost any old SO feature request

Comment: Oh, and the worst part of UV? You got ten "votes" which you could assign to different feature requests. Posting your own chewed up at least one vote. So, report ten bugs & you're out of votes. At one time, I had at least three different accounts active on the site just because I'd used up all the votes and was still finding bugs (posting anonymously worked, unless you actually cared about keeping track of the status of your requests - remember, linking didn't really work reliably).

Comment: There is [a Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UserVoice#History) for it.